# Issue using StreamBridge in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have currently deployed this sample app [standalone-stream-sample](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/standalone-stream-sample/) on my kubernetes cluster and am trying to modify the Sender application to use a StreamBridge to publish messages like below (instead of using the Supplier function):

`streamBridge.send("sendEvents-out-0", usageDetail);`

The flow for the stream looks like this:

`usage-detail-sender app -> usage-cost-processor app -> usage-cost-logger app`

But for some reason, when the message is sent by the sender, it is not picked up by the processor application. I'm not getting any errors (so it seems like it's being published somewhere), but how do I set it up to publish the messages so that the other app can pick them up. This is what the config looks like in application.properties for the sender app:

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.sendEvents-out-0=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=usage-detail
```

This is what the config looks like for the processor app:

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.processUsageCost-in-0=input
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.processUsageCost-out-0=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=usage-detail
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=usage-cost
```

Comment: First you don't need to use StreamBridge to send messages. It was specifically designed for cases where the source of the Message is outside of s-c-stream (e.g., HTTP). A simple Function effectively create two bindings (input and output) with binding name conventions described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_and_binding_names). In any event, without looking at your entire application it is not possible to say what may be the issue. Perhaps you can push it to Github so we can take a look.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky the scenario I am thinking about is something like this: say you have a source application that is some kind of listener and it has an onMessage() method that periodically receives messages, and when a message is received, you want to write it to an output topic. Would you use StreamBridge for something like that? Or could you just use a Function on that method as well which would write to the topic? Thanks!

Comment: No i would simply use function (as described above). Your function effectively becomes a message listener, since binder's `onMessage` will delegate to function and function's output will be sent to the output destination

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky, if I were to need to process messages coming in via HTTP REST and "supply" them to Kafka, do I need StreamBridge in addition to a function or does StreamBridge take the place of the functional approach? Also, if I'm using StreamBridge what is the correct way to define the output binding if spring.cloud.stream.source is deprecated?

Comment: @ccellist, yes this is one specific use case for why StreamBridge exists in the first place - to bridge non-stream source (i.e., http) with stream.

Comment: Cool, thank you @OlegZhurakousky. Also, if I'm using StreamBridge what is the correct way to define the output binding if spring.cloud.stream.source is deprecated?

Comment: `spring.cloud.stream.input/output-bindings` - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages

Comment: Did this ever work? I am facing the same issue. I am using StreamBridge and trying to send and event to Kafka. But its not able to read the producer configuration.

I tried with spring.cloud.stream.source and spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings